# how to make Visual studio read from google searches. C#

Tags: c#

I am making an AI that uses google searches to learn, I know there is a way to open a link through Process.Start("https://Google.com") but is there a way to then read data from the page you just opened? preferably without google's API. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

> Process.Start("https://Google.com");

you call only the web page with a browser, but here with you get the whole page, but of course only as HTML, but this can be sniffed.

```
using System.Net;

namespace test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string html = GetData("https://Google.com");

            Console.WriteLine(html);
        }

        static string GetData(string url)
        {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                return wc.DownloadString(url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You call the function, and get the whole web page. Is that what you mean?

Comment: great, that was exactly what i was hoping for and to be sure, is the data in a constant format?

Comment: You get a string of the whole web page, so not only the text but also html. You can then search it with regex or something like that.

Comment: understood thx, also can you tell me if i got to import any libraries?

Comment: oh sorry i forgot a using, look at my answer at the top i added it there

Comment: Now look again (at the top), you call the function. And put your link in the brackets. Got it?

Comment: i am sorry that was a stupid question to ask, yes i totally see it and figured it out seconds before you answered

Comment: Everything is fine, have fun and success.